# Different ways to calculate Lipschitz constant of the LASSO problem

Tags: convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions

The LASSO problem is well-known problem in ML community given by:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{1}{n}\|Ax-b\|^2_2 + \frac{\lambda}{n}\|x\|_1
\end{equation}

This equation appears in [paper1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04407) on page 9 (S2GD algorithm). Now, there are two ways to calculate lipschitz constant of the above problem.

1. $L=\frac{2}{n}\|A^TA\|_2$ which is by going through Hessian way.This can be approximated by $L=\frac{2}{n}\|A^T\|\|A\|$ since former one is costly to compute(from memory perspective).
2. $L=2*max(sum(X^2,2))$ (in MATLAB, $X^2$ is X.^2). This is basically computing row square; summing and taking max. This is how author in the above paper and their another [paper2](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.1666.pdf) has calculated lipschitz constant (however for logistic regression on page 18 of paper2).

My concern is the two ways of calculating L  should give the same result but it's NOT!. Specifically, S2GD algorithm is taking long time to converge on different data sets with `L` set as above.
 Can somebody tell me the right way to calculate the lipschitz constant for the lasso problem applicable to S2GD algorithm?

Comment: Your problem (which formula works in matlab, why slow, etc.) is more of "computational science" than mathematics. Standard form of objective: $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|_2^2 + \lambda\|x\|_1$. To compute Lipschitz constant for the **smooth part**, in  Python do: L = scipy.linalg.svdvals(A)[0] ** 2

Comment: The right thing to do is to adapt L over the course of the algorithm. A fixed L is necessarily over conservative.

Comment: Agreed that it's more of "computational science". However, the author in the above paper uses a technique to calculate L which is to take the `max` of `sum` of each feature vector $a_i$. Can you tell me if this approach  will yield the same L as calculated from method using Hessian way?

Comment: @MichaelGrant. Can you point out some papers to choose L adaptively?

Comment: Why would you expect different non-equivalent techniques to arrive at the same L? That makes no sense to me. As for a paper, look at TFOCS.

Comment: Then L calculated by which of the two methods be taken is my concern. L calculated as suggested by authors is working on only one data set they have used. For other data sets, L is too high. Following Hessian way also gives very high L which makes S2GD impractical.

Comment: Your problem is believing that algorithms described in papers are actually meant to be used in practice. :-) Seriously, go check out [TFOCS](http://cvxr.com/tfocs/). Sure, we wrote a paper, but *after* we had software we liked. And one of the *first* things we had to tackle was figuring out a way to select $L$ intelligently and adaptively.